# Iterate and append the different values from JSON into a variable

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to iterate and append the `QId` and `Answer` from the payload, desired output expected would be like `12|Yes&&13|Yes&&14|Yes&&15|Yes&&16|Yes&&17|Yes&&`.

All I wanted is to concatenate `QId` and `Answer` before it saves to the database. How could I achieve this

`Qstans = str(qid)+'|'+ answer+'&&'.join([str(qid)+'|'+(answer) for ran in request.data])` this line which append the values

output which I'm getting

`12|Yes12|Yes&&12|Yes&&12|Yes&&12|Yes&&12|Yes&&12|Yes`

payload:

```
0: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "Yes", QId: 150…}
1: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "No", QId: 151…}
2: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "Yes", QId: 152…}
3: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "Yes", QId: 153…}
4: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "No", QId: 154…}
5: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "Yes", QId: 155…}
6: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "No", QId: 156…}
```

code here:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def SaveUserResponse(request):
   
  if request.method == 'POST': 

    for ran in request.data:
        qid = ran.get('QId')
        answer = ran.get('Answer')
        Qstans = str(qid)+'|'+ answer+'&&'.join([str(qid)+'|'+(answer) for ran in request.data])
        print(Qstans)
```

Comment: can you provide a **minimal code**, keeping only what is strictly required to illustrate the operation you want to achieve? And the **input** that is received

Comment: I have edited the code and added the payload @mozway

Comment: this is unfortunately not a valid python object

Comment: this Django part but the logic where I stucked that was completely python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a list comprehension within a loop, which is unnecessary for (what I understand is) your goal. Within the comprehension, you're also using variables that you assigned in the loop, leading to all the Q/A values being 12 and "Yes" respectively.

Simply swapping out the loop and using:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
    Qstans = '&&'.join(str(ran.get('QId')) + '|' + str(ran.get('Answer')) for ran in request.data)
```

should be sufficient.
I haven't been able to test this because you haven't provided a Python object as mozway mentioned in the comments, but this should work with maybe minor tweaks (such as appending a `'&&'` in case you require it).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be double iteration, so you could try this code instead

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def SaveUserResponse(request):
   
  if request.method == 'POST': 
    Qstans = ""
    for ran in request.data:
        qid = ran.get('QId')
        answer = ran.get('Answer')
        Qstans = Qstans + str(qid)+'|'+ answer+'&&'
    print(Qstans)
```

notice how the print(Qstans) is outside the loop